# Return word before or after a string with newline characters

Tags: javascript

**In short:** I want to return the word right before or after a newline character in a string. How would I accomplish that?

I want to return: **1,150** and **Svendborg**

**This is my string:**

```
var newline = /\n/;

var str = "Specialzed Road Expert 2017\nkr.1,150 - Svendborg\n\nSpecialzed"
```

Comment: `2017` is also before a newline, can you clarify on your rules please?

Comment: why not 2017, which is right before \n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will essentially match a whole line with a leading and trailing newline character with groups to match just the first and last "words".

```js
var str = "Specialzed Road Expert 2017\nkr.1,150 - Svendborg\n\nSpecialzed";
var matches = str.match(/\n([^\s]+).*?([^\s]+)\n/);
console.log(matches);
```

Your words would be in `matches[1]` and `matches[2]` with `matches[0]` being the whole line.